# Hide the default title-box (tooltip) from a link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know how to achive a customized "title-box" when hovering over a link. That would be something like this:

```
a[title]:hover:after {
   content: attr(title);
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top: 100%;
   background-color:#ffffff;
   color:#000000;
}
```

Then the box is display with the description you enter into the title of a-tag:

But also the "ordinary yellowish" description box is shown and I don't want that. Is it possible to hide the default title-box?

```
<a href"blabla.php" title="{description}">Bla bla bla</a>
```

If I do something like this

```
$("a").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().attr('title', 'description of the link');},
    function(){$(this).stop().attr();
});
```

Then no title is shown at all (of course)

I've also tested with:

```
$("a").mouseover(function(e){ e.preventDefault();} );
```

with no luck...

The thing I really want is to replace the default "title-box" with a customized. Is this possible without having the default "title box" visible?

**UPDATE:**
Even though I got my answer which I'm very satisfied with I actually was kind of dissapointed because I thought the idea of using a[title] in css3 was cool, but actually too complex to achive what I wanted (not complex in programming terms, but unessecary to involve javascript). I've decided to do this the "old way" by creating an ordered list

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1
    <ul class="description">
    <li>description</li>
    </ul> 
</li>
<li>Item 2
    <ul class="description">
    <li>description</li>
    </ul> 
</li>
</ul>
```

and show descriptions when hovering on the item, something like:

```
.description {display:none;}
li:hover > ul {display:block;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JS you could first change the attribute from `title` to `data-title`, and then use `attr(data-title)` in your CSS to show your 'hover-box".

I think you can't prevent the browser from showing the `title` attribute: but if you rename it (to `data-title` for instance) it shouldn't be shown.

Comment: Glad it helped. Regarding the update, I prefer your original version (especially on a semantic aspect): if JS is disabled, then the `title` is displayed using the browser default, otherwise it's customized as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep title value somewhere else before destroying it.
Custom data attribute can be used for custom title.
Something like this....

```
  $(this).attr("data-title",$(this).attr("title"));
  $(this).stop().attr('title', 'description of the link');
```

and change your attribute in css accordingly.

Comment: This was kind of exact same answer as oliverpool had, but thanks for the code :-)

Comment: yup ... I got to know this after posting mine and getting the page refreshed :)